# How to send dictionary data with redirect function in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to send a dictionary by the redirect method. But not getting it in the redirected template. I tried to pass the dictionary like it used to pass in the render function but I don't think I am doing this in the right way. I also tried **HttpResponseRedirect** but that doesn't work too. I'm getting a weird error

```
NoReverseMatch at /
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        url  = request.POST.get('url', '')

        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")
        p_name = soup.find_all("h2",attrs={"class": "a-size-mini"})
        p_price = soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class": "a-price-whole"})
        p_image = soup.findAll('img', {'class':'s-image','src':re.compile('.jpg')})

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="product_file.csv"'


        for name,price,image in zip(p_name,p_price,p_image):
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            row = writer.writerow([image['src'],name.text, price.text,])

            name_data  = [data.text for data in p_name]
            price_data = [data.text for data in p_price]
            image_data = [data['src'] for data in p_image]
            dec = {'name':name_data, 'price':price_data, 'image':image_data, 'url':url}

        return redirect('data', dec)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('upload',views.upload,name='upload'),
    path('data',views.data,name='data')
]
```

Comment: can you show us the urls.py? there must be a url with the name as ''data" else this will not work

Comment: @SammyJ please check now

Comment: maybe you must add a `/` at the end in urls.py just like they have mentioned here, (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path), does it work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `redirect()` method and pass in the dict to another view function.You can do something similar to this.

```py
def index(request):
     ...        
     dec = {'name':name_data, 'price':price_data, 'image':image_data, 'url':url}
     return redirect('data', kwargs = dec)
     ...
```

and then you need to have the view function that you are using for redirect accepting an argument `**kwargs` make sure to change the `urls.py`.

```py
def data(request, **kwargs):
    // use **kwargs and render the template with the dict.
```

### If you want to get the params as query parameter from the url.

You can make use of direct urls in the `redirect()` method.

```py
from django.urls import reverse
import urllib.parse

def index(request):
    ...
    dec = {'name':name_data, 'price':price_data, 'image':image_data, 'url':url}
    url = '{}?{}'.format(reverse('data'), urllib.parse.urlencode(dec)) # /data/?name=abc&price=45 ..
    return redirect(url)
```

and then use the params.

```py
def data(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    # Do something here
```

Comment: still getting the error `Reverse for 'data' with keyword arguments `

Comment: You need to change the `urls.py` as well. Can you add `urls.py` in your question

Comment: Yes **url.py** is there now

Comment: do you want the dict keys in the url parameter? ex: `xyz.com/?name=sdf&price=23`

Comment: Is this possible? because in dict name is key of **name_data** which is a list and contains almost 16 values.

Comment: Its possible, updated the answer! though so many values are not ideally passed as  param

Comment: can you please tell me from where to import urlencode? because I'm getting this error `name 'urlencode' is not defined`

Comment: `urllib` is a standard package, you just need to import it in the `views.py` file.I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: for python2 it should be `from urllib import urlencode` and for python3 it wouls be `from urllib.parse import urlencode`

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without the URL?

Comment: You can include it in the path itself but again that won't be good enough.

Comment: So that means we can't pass the dictionary in the redirect method without URL. Can suggest me the other way without including URL.

Comment: did some research,I think, it wont be possible with `redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be by using sessions.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def source_view(request):
    data = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

    # Store data in the session
    request.session['resp_data'] = data

    # Redirect to the target view
    return redirect('my_app:my_view')
```

In your view.py access 'resp_data'.

```
def my_view(request):
    # Retrieve data from the session
    send_data = request.session.get('resp_data', {})

    # Your view logic
    # ...

    # You can also remove the data from the session if needed
    del request.session['resp_data']

    return JsonResponse(send_data)  # Return data as JSON response
```